# Is adding multiple elements in a list comprehension possible?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm wondering whether it's possible to add multiple elements to a list within a list comprehension.

For instance, if I want a list consisting of the numbers 1 to 10, I can write:

```
[k | k <- [1..10]]
```

However, is there also a way to do this by always adding `k` *and* `k+1` in the same step, and just take only the odd numbers `k`? Following code is invalid but perhaps explains better what I'm trying to do:

```
[k, k+1 | k <- [1, 3..10]]
```

Currently, the closest thing to this (that I am aware of) is the following:

```
foldl1 (++) [[k, k + 1] | k <- [1, 3..10]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some alternatives, none of which is significantly better than what you propose.

```
concat [ [k, k+1] | k <- [1, 3 .. 10] ]
join   [ [k, k+1] | k <- [1, 3 .. 10] ]
[ x | k <- [1, 3 .. 10], x <- [k,k+1] ]
[1, 3 .. 10] >>= (\x -> [x, x + 1])
do x <- [1, 3 .. 10] ; [x, x+1]
```

Note that `foldl1 (++)`, as in your solution, will abort the program with a runtime error if it finds an empty lists-of-lists. The above alternatives have no such problem.

Comment: Thank you for you answer and providing alternatives!

Comment: Another one is `[1, 3 .. 10] >>= (\x -> [x, x + 1])`.

Comment: ... or equivalently `do` `x <- [1, 3 .. 10]` `[x, x+1]`.